# Measurement of energy consumption using profiler in windows 10 mobile device

Tags: mobile, win-universal-app, profiler, energy

I'm trying to profile energy consumption in a real Windows 10 mobile device with ARM-class processor. However, to do so, we need to disconnect from USB cable, because a direct feeding by means of USB seems to distort measurements, in addition energy-aware objects (like AggregateBattery) defaults to null. But when device is disconnected from the computer, and connected via WiFi, seems that Visual Studio does not support such remote debugging. VS2015 remote tools are not  available for Windows 10 mobile phones with ARM processors, at least, we couldn't find a suitable installer for the platform. Is there a way to profile energy consumption for a UWP application, running in a real Win10 mobile device, using VS2015?

Comment: What are you trying to profile? Why do you need to use VS2015 to do the profiling?

Comment: Hi. I wasn't notified for your input, hence my delay to comment, I apologise for this. We need to estimate the power consumption for a given job. For instance ,training an artificial neural network. The new batteryreport object seems to have a software model that estimates remaining energy by performing certain internal measurements that feeds the algorithm, but we have to capture these data in a customary fashion, VS2015 offers a robust visualization facility. the goal is to predict how many milliamperes.hour are consumed to train a given pattern with a given artificial neural model.